# How to use INCLUDE in MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, db2

I am trying to convert `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` from DB2 to mysql . I just want to know how to use INCLUDE in MySQL queries .I have searched in MySQL document and i din;t find anything .
This is the sample DB2 query :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SAMPLE ON MY_TABLE(ID)
  INCLUDE(FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3, FIELD_4) COMPRESS NO ALLOW REVERSE SCANS#
```

and also i want to know `COMPRESS NO ALLOW REVERSE SCANS` is allowed in MySQL ? Any help or suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple: none of these options are supported in mysql and there is no equivalent option either. Db2 and mysql are two different products, they work differently.

Comment: so how to write these query in mysql ?

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SAMPLE ON MY_TABLE(ID)` that's all.

Comment: So no need of `INCLUDE` fields ?  or should i write like `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SAMPLE ON MY_TABLE(ID,FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3, FIELD_4)` ?

Comment: This is not the same as creating a unique index just on the id field. It seems that you do not really understand what those options in db2 mean.